# How to use library on an external project without uploading to NPM? Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I have 2 different angular apps and both of them will need to use a lot of the same services and interfaces, so I created added a third separate project and created a library there with some services and interfaces. After building the library I added the following to one of the 2 apps

package.json:

```
"daleeli-lib": "file:../SharedServices/dist/my-lib",
```

The problem with this is if I change the folder name of one of the files I will get an error as the library is no longer referenced:

```
Cannot find module 'my-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Is there a workaround to this without uploading the library to NPM?

Comment: Do i understand it correctly. You install a local dependency, and then you move your local dependency to another location?

Comment: Yes, I installed a local dependency but this is error prone as moving the dependency elsewhere or changing the name of the folder it is in will cause an unreferenced error

Comment: Well this is to be expected. Unlike normal dependency installation, installing a local dependency creates a sort of symbolic link between the project and the dependency. So moving the dependency or renaming the folder will break the link. Only solution is to update your package.json if you do any of these changes.

Comment: You could try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local this. But then each time you update the libary you need to reinstall it on your project, as this way you lose the benefit of the symlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm link like well explained in this link.
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/complete-beginner-guide-to-publish-an-angular-library-to-npm-d42343801660

or you can build your lib in locale and do a npm package.
Import this pakage in your web app, and do an npm install 'yorfilepath'